# How to open url from top in webview

Tags: android, webview

In `activity.xml` i am using this code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/web_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv_brow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.80">
</WebView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In `Activity` i am using this code

```
    brow= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv_brow);
    nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.web_scroll_view);
    nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
    brow.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
    brow.loadUrl( webURL );
```

this is working fine it is open website . Issues this that if i scroll Web Page and click any URL then next web page is not open from top.Please help me how can i open next page from top

Comment: kind why you are taking NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `WebViewClient` and do this to scroll it top every time a new page opens:

```
brow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
    webView.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
});
```

As you already have your `OurViewClient`, I would suggest overriding the `onPageFinished` method and put the `scrollTo` method inside.

Comment: I also suggest you to remove the ‘NestedScrollView’. I don’t think you need it.